# I need to plot a simple animated arrow vector in 3 dimensional space

Tags: java, python, plot, matplotlib, blender

I am trying to display a single magnetic field vector (point in space, with arrow from origin) using data from Android phone sensors. I wrote a simple server in Python to poll the phone for sensor data, and I want to plot the data received in real time. I'm looking for a simple solution, but I can't find any.

I looked at matplotlib, blender, and visual python but I couldn't find a simple enough solution that simply takes the 3 coordinates and plots. The data received is simply a vector with 3 points. The arrow from the origin is not so important, I just want to be able to visualize the moving point in 3d space.

Also, if necessary, I can rewrite the server in Java and use a Java plotting library. I just need some suggestions, and short code examples that achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw scene by VPython very easily:

```
from visual import *
import math

def make_grid(unit, n):
    nunit = unit * n
    f = frame()
    for i in xrange(n+1):
        if i%5==0: 
            color = (1,1,1)
        else:
            color = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

        curve(pos=[(0,i*unit,0), (nunit, i*unit, 0)],color=color,frame=f)
        curve(pos=[(i*unit,0,0), (i*unit, nunit, 0)],color=color,frame=f)
    return f

arrow(pos=(0,0,0), axis=(5,0,0), color=(1,0,0), shaftwidth=0.1)    
arrow(pos=(0,0,0), axis=(0,5,0), color=(0,1,0), shaftwidth=0.1)    
arrow(pos=(0,0,0), axis=(0,0,5), color=(0,0,1), shaftwidth=0.1)    
grid_xy = make_grid(0.5, 10)
grid_xz = make_grid(0.5, 10)
grid_xz.rotate(angle=pi/2, axis=(1,0,0), origin=(0,0,0))
grid_yz = make_grid(0.5, 10)
grid_yz.rotate(angle=-pi/2, axis=(0,1,0), origin=(0,0,0))
sphere(radius=0.3)

obj = arrow(pos=(0,0,0), axis=(1,2,3), shaftwidth=0.3)
th = 0
while True:
    rate(20)
    obj.axis = (3*math.cos(th), 3*math.sin(th), 2)
    th += 0.04
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

VPython is very simple:

```
pointer = arrow(pos=(0,0,0), axis=(1,2,3), shaftwidth=1)
```

Just change the axis=(1,2,3) to the 3 points in your vector. More information can be found [here](http://vpython.org/contents/docs/visual/arrow.html).

Comment: How do I plot the vector in real time?

Comment: But lastly, do you know how I can add a grid, to show the x, y, and z axes?

Answer (score 1):

If c++ is an option you should really take a look at VTK

http://www.vtk.org/

It is very powerful to display 3D vector fields, and is pretty easy to use

Comment: +1. As a side note, you can use VTK in python, both through the official wrappers (which are a direct clone of the C++ interface) or through more "pythonic" wrappers such as TVTK or Mayavi.  Using VTK directly is overkill for this, but Mayavi's `mlab` intervface makes it quite easy.